# Send MySQL table via email

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP script (below) that I call using a CRON job which takes a backup of my MySQL database, gzips it and then emails the gzipped file to me. Over time the database has gotten bigger and bigger and I've discovered that all I really need was one particular table (not the whole database) - i.e. the 'orders' table. I was wondering if there was any way to extend the existing script to only gzip one specified table. Thanks very much, overflow-ers :)

```
<?php

$label = '
****************************************************/
';


/***************************************************
    Database settings
****************************************************/
    $db_server          = 'localhost';              //     Database server, usually "localhost", 
                                                    // on (mt)     servers something like internal-db.s12345.gridserver.com
    $db_name            = 'XXXXX';              // Database     name, leave empty for 'all databases'
    $db_user            = 'XXXXX';              // Database         username
    $db_pass            = 'XXXXX';              // Database     password



/***************************************************
    E-mail settings
****************************************************/
    $website            = 'XXXXX.com';          // Your site's     domain (without www. part)
    $send_to            = 'XXXXX@XXXXX.com';                //     backup file will be sent to?
    $from               = 'email@' . $website;  // some     hosting providers wonâ€™t let you send backups from invalid e-mail     address



/***************************************************
    Misc options
****************************************************/

    $full_path      = '/home/XXXXX/public_html/XXXXX'; 
    // Full path to folder where you are running the script,     usually "/home/username/public_html"
    // (mt) servers have something like     "/nfs/c01/h01/mnt/12345/domains/yourdomain.mobi/html/tools/backup2ma    il"


    $delete_backup  = false;                            
        // delete gziped database from server after sending?

    $send_log       = false;                            
    // send follow-up report?
    // - true = send log file to an e-mail after each backup     transfer
    // - false = don't send log file, just leave it on the server



/***************************************************
    If everything goes well, you shouldn't
    modify anything below.
****************************************************/

error_reporting(E_ALL);

echo '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0     Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-    transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Backup2mail status [' . $website . ']</title>
        <style type="text/css">body { background: #000; color: #    0f0; font-family: \'Courier New\', Courier; }</style>
    </head>
    <body>';

function date_stamp() {
    global $html_output;
    $backup_date = date('Y-m-d-H-i');
    echo 'Database backup date: ' . $backup_date . '<br />';
    return $backup_date;
}

function backup_filename() {
    global $db_name, $date_stamp, $html_output;
    $db_backup_filename = ($db_name == '' ? 'all_databases' :     $db_name) . '_' . $date_stamp . '.sql.gz';
    echo 'Database backup file: ' . $db_backup_filename . '<br     />';
    return $db_backup_filename;
}

function db_dump() {
    global $db_server, $db_name, $db_user, $db_pass,     $backup_filename, $html_output;
    $cmd = 'mysqldump -u ' . $db_user . ' -h ' . $db_server . ' --    password=' . $db_pass . ' ' . ($db_name == '' ? '--all-databases' :     $db_name) . ' | gzip > ' . $backup_filename;
    $dump_status = (passthru($cmd) === false) ? 'No' : 'Yes';

    echo 'Command executed? ' . $dump_status . '<br />';
    return $dump_status;
}

function send_attachment($file, $file_is_db = true) {
    global $send_to, $from, $website, $delete_backup,     $html_output;

    $sent       = 'No';

    $subject    = 'MySQL backup - ' . ($file_is_db ? 'db dump' :     'report') . ' [' . $website . ']';
    $boundary   = md5(uniqid(time()));
    $mailer     = 'Sent by Backup2Mail (c) Marko Dugonjic,     www.maratz.com, 2005-2009.';

    $body = 'Database backup file:' . "\n" . ' - ' . $file . "\n    \n";
    $body .= '---' . "\n" . $mailer;

    $headers  = 'From: ' . $from . "\n";
    $headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: multipart/mixed; boundary="' .     $boundary . '";' . "\n";
    $headers .= 'This is a multi-part message in MIME format. ';
    $headers .= 'If you are reading this, then your e-mail client     probably doesn\'t support MIME.' . "\n";
    $headers .= $mailer . "\n";
    $headers .= '--' . $boundary . "\n";

    $headers .= 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1"' .     "\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit' . "\n";
    $headers .= $body . "\n";
    $headers .= '--' . $boundary . "\n";

    $headers .= 'Content-Disposition: attachment;' . "\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-Type: Application/Octet-Stream; name="' .     $file . "\"\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64' . "\n\n";
    $headers .= chunk_split(base64_encode(implode('', file    ($file)))) . "\n";
    $headers .= '--' . $boundary . '--' . "\n";

    if (mail($send_to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
        $sent = 'Yes';      
        echo ($file_is_db ? 'Backup file' : 'Report') . ' sent to     ' . $send_to . '.<br />';
        if ($file_is_db) {
            if ($delete_backup) {
                unlink($file);
                echo 'Backup file REMOVED from disk.<br />';
            } else {
                echo 'Backup file LEFT on disk.<br />';
            }
        }
    } else {
        echo '<span style="color: #f00;">' . ($file_is_db ?     'Database' : 'Report') . ' not sent! Please check your mail     settings.</span><br />';
    }

    echo 'Sent? ' . $sent;

    return $sent;
}

function write_log() {
    global $backup_filename, $date_stamp, $send_log, $label,     $full_path;

    $log_file = $full_path . '/backup_log.txt';
    if (!$handle = fopen($log_file, 'a+')) exit;
    if (chmod($log_file, 0644) && is_writable($log_file)) {

        echo '<h2>Mysqldump...</h2>';
        $dumped         = db_dump();

        echo '<h2>Sending db...</h2>';
        $log_content    = "\n" . $date_stamp . "\t\t\t" . $dumped     . "\t\t\t" . send_attachment($backup_filename);

        echo '<h2>Writing log...</h2>';

        $log_header = '';
        if (filesize($log_file) == '0') {
            $log_header .= $label . "\n\n";
            $log_header .= 'Backup log' . "\n";
            $log_header .=     '----------------------------------------------' . "\n";
            $log_header .= 'DATESTAMP:                      DUMPED      MAILED' . "\n";
            $log_header .=     '----------------------------------------------';

            if (fwrite($handle, $log_header) === false) exit;
        }

        echo 'Log header written: ';
        if (fwrite($handle, $log_header) === false) {
            echo 'no<br />' . "\n";
            exit;
        } else {
            echo 'yes<br />' . "\n";
        }

        echo 'Log status written: ';    
        if (fwrite($handle, $log_content) === false) {
            echo 'no<br />' . "\n";
            exit;
        } else {
            echo 'yes<br />' . "\n";
        }

    }

    fclose($handle);

    if ($send_log) {
        echo '<h2>Sending log...</h2>';
        send_attachment($log_file, false);
    }
}



echo '<h2>Setup</h2>';
$date_stamp         = date_stamp();
$backup_filename    = backup_filename();
$init               = write_log();

echo '<br /><br />...<br /><br />If all letters are green and     you received the files, you\'re good to go!<br />Remove '#' from     this folderâ€™s .htaccess file NOW.</body></html>';

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the mysqldump docs (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) the general format for the mysqldump command is;

```
mysqldump [options] db_name [tbl_name ...]
```

So, you should just be able to append the list of tables you wish to dump (or a singular table in your case) to the command.